# Prevent others from leaching/downloading fonts using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, font-face

Im not sure if this is a duplicate, if it is, please accept my apologies in advance. How can I prevent others from leaching/downloading my `@font-face` fonts `(eot, svg, ttf, woff)` using `.htaccess` and only allowing my domain to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the guys over at the #httpd channel on IRC. I've finally found the htaccess block of code to prevent people from hotlinking to my fonts.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^https?://([^/]*)?example\.com/" local_ref=1
SetEnvIf Referer ^$ local_ref=1

<FilesMatch "\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from env=local_ref
</FilesMatch>
```

Source: [Apache Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DisableImageHotLinking).

For some reason, the code which @joshhendo provided me didn't work for both font file types and images. I'm not sure how `.htaccess` works, perhaps others with more experience can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent hot linking (see http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html ). This could be changed for font faces), which would allow only pages from your domain to access it. This won't stop people downloading the fonts and uploading them to their own servers, but there's nothing you can do about that.

The following code should work (it's from the URL above, but I've modified it to include the fonts you mentioned. Obviously you will need to change mysite.com to your domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)$ - [F]
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, but for some reason I can still access my live sites fonts thru my local dev site using the rewrites you gave me. I'm not sure, but it might have to do with my hosting, its not my first time seeing changes in `.htaccess` 24 hrs later.

Comment: Do you think you could try it with images? The use the code in the linked tutorial to find the rewrite code for images. If it blocks images, then obviously the code doesn't work in the same way for fonts as it does for images. If it doesn't block them though, then there's possibly something up with the hosting configuration.

Comment: yea i was ahead of you on that one. It doesn't seem to work. Funny thing is i've got `mod_rewrites` for url redirects, which are respected, not sure why these aren't. I'm guessing its a waiting game, I've had the same problem with my hosting in regards to seeing updates to changes in my `htaccess`.

Comment: Ok. Well, here's hoping the code that I posted does work when your hosting provider fixes the issue.

Comment: I contacted my hosting provider about this issue with a cliche "Thank you for contacting us, but we cannot provide coding support". I'm pretty much SOL on this one. I'll keep looking around. Maybe someone else can shed light onto this issue. Thanks for your time @joshhendo